# How can I make a button that changes the text inside when clicked?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button that changes the text inside the button by pressing the button, but I don't know how! :(

I used :hover, but when I move the mouse pointer away, it goes back to its previous state.

Comment: You can use the `:visited` pseudo-class for the anchor tag `<a>` and style the anchor tag as a button to change the text. But this will only change it one way i.e. you won't be able to return back to the previous text on clicking it again. I would suggest to use `javascript` instead of just `html` and `css`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility of solving it with the pseudo-class :hover and the use of data attributes. The idea of this solution is that you hide the original button text, add an empty content and then use hover over the element to show the content of the data attribute.

I'll show you how in the following example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #F2CD5C;
  text-align: center;
 
}
.container {
  margin-top: 30vh;
}
/* 
MARK BUTTON:
In the button styles, it is necessary to hide the original text that we generated, to create the correct spacing and the data attribute text can overlap

The text color must be the same as the button background. 
Position must be relative.

*/
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
  background: black;
}

/*
MARK USE :before and :after
Setup pseudo-element ::before with content: ""; and position must be absolute and setup with the original position text inside the button.

Write ::after with the exact text inside button = Click me! with the same position and setup to ::before pseudo-element

*/
.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
}
.button::after {
  content: "Click me!";
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

.button::before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
}

.button:hover:before{
  opacity: 1;
}

.button:hover:after{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button" data-hover="Hello world!">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

The code uses pseudo-elements ::before and ::after to display different text when the button is hovered over. The text "Click me!" is set as the content for the ::after pseudo-element, while the ::before pseudo-element gets its content from the "data-hover" attribute. When the button is hovered over, the ::before pseudo-element's opacity becomes 1 and the ::after pseudo-element's opacity becomes 0, effectively hiding and showing different text on the button.

I hope this can help you solve your question. Anyway, this solution is not clean, we should handle the DOM using JavaScript.

Reference Links
[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to do this using javascript, hope that helps.

## HTML

```
 <button class="btn">Hey, click me!</button>
```

## JS

first I store the button in a variable

```
var button = document.querySelector(".btn")
```

then I add an event listener to the button with the "click" event, which will make the function "function()" be executed whenever the button is clicked

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){})
```

now, I define the function to change the text of the button using "this" to access the button of the function and ".textContent" to change the text that was inside

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.textContent = "Hey, you clicked me!"
})
```

Click "run" for a preview

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".btn")
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.textContent = "Hey, you clicked me!"
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hey, click me!</button>
```